# Redis response various $ values when getting key value

Tags: redis

I am currently looking into using Redis and looking into making a client library for it.

I am doing some experimenting to understand how it works by creating a telnet connection to the redis server on port 6379.

When I set a key using `SET mykey myvalue` it returns +OK. Does the + mean anything as that doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.

When I then try and fetch the key using `GET mykey` I then get the following

```
$7
myvalue
```

From what I can see in the documentation it is only supported to return the value, so why am I getting $7 back. Does it have any particular meaning, or can I just scrap it and just look at the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well documented at [Redis Protocol specification](https://redis.io/topics/protocol). I recommend you read it thoroughly before attempting to write your own client and/or just one of the existing [Redis clients](https://redis.io/clients)

The `+` denotes a simple string - ref: https://redis.io/topics/protocol#resp-simple-strings

> Simple Strings are encoded in the following way: a plus character, followed by a string that cannot contain a CR or LF character (no newlines are allowed), terminated by CRLF (that is "\r\n").
>
> Simple Strings are used to transmit non binary safe strings with minimal overhead. For example many Redis commands reply with just "OK" on success, that as a RESP Simple String is encoded with the following 5 bytes:

```
"+OK\r\n"
```

The `$` denotes a bulk string - ref: https://redis.io/topics/protocol#resp-bulk-strings

> Bulk Strings are used in order to represent a single binary safe string up to 512 MB in length.
>
> Bulk Strings are encoded in the following way:
>
> - A "$" byte followed by the number of bytes composing the string (a prefixed length), terminated by CRLF.
> - The actual string data.
> - A final CRLF.
>
> So the string "foobar" is encoded as follows:

```
"$6\r\nfoobar\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I couldn't find anything about it at all, I apparently don't know how to use Google :(.

Comment: I'm giving private Google lessons for $7 ;P

Comment: Maybe I should take you up on it :)